# Separable spaces isomorphic

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am reading a proof and it states the following without proof:
Two separable Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic iff there are sequences $(x_n)\subset X$ and $(y_n)\subset Y$ such that $\overline{sp}\{x_n \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}=X$ and $\overline{sp}\{y_n \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}=Y$ and $c\|\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx_n\|\leq \|\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_ny_n\|\leq C\|\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx_n\|$for some $c,C>0$ and all $(a_n)\subset \mathbb{R}$.

I can prove <= easily but I am having trouble with the other direction.
So far I have taken countable dense subsets $(x_n)$ of $X$ and $(y_n)$ of $Y$. These then automatically satisfy the closed linear span requirement. I am not sure how to verify the norm requirement. I know it must use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic but can't see how.

Could anyone please help me?
Thank you

Comment: An isomorphism $T:X\rightarrow Y$ will map a dense set in $X$ to a dense set in $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a set with dense linear span and $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be an isomorphism. Put $y_n=Tx_n$. Then $\{y_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ has dense linear span in $Y$. Now let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x_n$ exists. For every $N$ the following inequality is true: $$\|\sum_{n=1}^N a_n x_n\|=\|T^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n Tx_n\|=\|T^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n y_n\|\le\|T^{-1}\|\|\sum_{n=1}^N a_n y_n\|.$$ Similarly one obtains $$\|\sum_{n=1}^N a_n y_n\|\le \|T\|\|\sum_{n=1}^N a_n x_n\|,$$ so  $$\frac{1}{\|T^{-1}\|}\|\sum_{n=1}^N a_n x_n\|\le\|\sum_{n=1}^N a_n y_n\|\le \|T\|\|\sum_{n=1}^N a_n x_n\|$$
for all $N$. Taking limits yields the claim.

Comment: I have already answered it, but it's nice to know I was correct ;)

Comment: does there exist two non-seperable Banach spaces which are not isomorphic?

Comment: @Tom and what about converse. How to prove this condition implies spaces are isomorphic

Comment: @Tom seperable Banach space itself can't prove the existence of Schauder basis as you have mentioned

Comment: @Sushil Assume WLOG that $\{x_n\}$ is linearly independent, map $x_n$ to $y_n$ and extend. The inequalities imply that this yields an isomorphism.

Comment: As for your other question, take any non-separable Hilbert space and $\ell^\infty$. These are both non-separable, but Hilbert spaces are reflexive, whereas $\ell^\infty$ is not.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Oh sorry I was asking for seperable Banach Space which are not isomorphic

Comment: @Sushil Then take $\ell^2$ and $C([0,1])$, the first is reflexive, whereas the second is not.

Comment: @VincentBoelens in your answer you assumed existence of Schauder basis (xn). But question doesn't ask. And I think two Banach space isomorphic would not imply existence of Schauder basis itself.

Comment: @Sushil You don't need a Schauder basis. The second inequality tells you that the operator I defined before is bounded on the span of the $\{x_n\}$. The first inequality tells you that the operator is injective and that the image is closed. Because the image contains all the $\{y_n\}$ it is also dense. So the image is $Y$.

Comment: @VincentBoelens why a sequence whose span dense in seperable space will exist